# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. Using webpack & less

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, less

I'm trying to set up a SDE with webpack, less and typescript.But I am stuck by the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js                                                                                            
Module parse failed: D:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\.0.1.5@source-map-loader\index.js!D:\wamp\www\project\src\index.js Unexpected token (8:4)                                                                                       
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                       
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:4)
```

This is my config file(webpack.config.js) of webpack:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",

    },
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        lessLoaders: [
            {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less?strictMath&noIeCompat"}
        ],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],
        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }, 

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./",
        colors: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

And package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^0.14.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.18",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.9.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Finally, the index.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as styles from "./Greeter.less";

import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello className={styles.html}/>,
    document.getElementById("example")
);
```

Do I need to add some extra loader plugins to compile my project?

---

This is the tsconfig.json file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/components/Hello.tsx"
    ]
}
```

And the Hello.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { className: string}

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <h1 className={this.props.className}>Hello from Typescript and React!</h1>;
    }
}
```

Comment: show me your tsconfig.json

Comment: This is my tsconfig.json

Comment: ·{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/components/Hello.tsx"
    ]
}·

Comment: share your Hello component as well

Comment: is index.js in es5 format?

Comment: Should I use the babel to compile the index.js to es5 format?

Comment: You need to use the babel loader to transpile your es6 code. Something like `{
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          plugins: []
        }
      },`